# Display array of objects based on property ReactJs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array like this:

```
user:[
  { name: "A", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "B", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "C", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "D", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "E", mobile: "123", status: "inactive"},
  { name: "F", mobile: "123", status: "inactive"},
];
```

Right now my code displays 4 records with "active" users first and "inactive" users at last

```
user.sort((a, b) =>a.status_id.localeCompare(b.status_id)).slice(0,4).map((d))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
active
active
active
active
```

But what I want to display is  - first half should be "active" and second half should be "inactive" and if there is no "inactive" user, then all should display "active" users

```
Displaying 4 records
active
active
inactive
inactive
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you are expecting to display 6 records finally?

Comment: @AmruthLS No,only 4 records

Comment: whats your logic to display 4 records ? 2 from active 2 from inactive ?

Comment: @AmruthLS Yes, 2 from active and 2 from inactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you

```js
let user = [
  { name: "A", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "B", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "C", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "D", mobile: "123", status: "active"},
  { name: "E", mobile: "123", status: "inactive"},
  { name: "F", mobile: "123", status: "inactive"},
];

let active = user.sort((a, b) =>a.status.localeCompare(b.status)).slice(0,2);
let inactive = user.sort((a, b) =>b.status.localeCompare(a.status)).slice(0,2);
let final = active.concat(inactive);
console.log(final)
```